# Treating a specific node in tree [vue-orgChart]

Tags: javascript, tree, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a tree using the `org-chart.vue` project ([link](https://github.com/spiritree/vue-orgchart)) and `Vue`.

Some of the code:

```
<div id="tree">
    <vo-basic :data="Tree" :pan="true" :zoom="true"></vo-basic>
</div>
```

It works great and converts the JSON file to the tree, but there is only one problem - I don't know how to handle a specific node in the tree. I would like to implement the following feature - everytime user clicks the node, it will pop a window with the details of the specific node.

I would like to implement something like this:

```
<vo-basic @click="showDetails(node)" :data="Tree" :pan="true" :zoom="true"></vo-basic>
```

Is it even possible? maybe there is a workaround for this issue?

Hope there are users who use this `JS` library.